# show a list of rent contacted by specific buyer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner of django-rest-framework. I am trying hard to understand the serializer and good api design. I dont want to dive directly into viewset and generics view like ListView, RetrieveAPIView and etc. I want to understand the serializer and APIView clearly so i drew the following criteria to solve them. However i could only solve 2 of the problem from below.

Here is the list of problems i drew to hone my rest api skill

```
"""
  return a list of rent
"""

"""
    return a list of rent or specific rent if token is give n
"""

"""
  return a list of rent contacted by specific buyer
"""

"""
  return a list of buyer that has contacted a specific rent
"""
```

Here is my model of Rent, Galleries and Contact. Rental and contact are separate app. Contact is to contact a rent owner to buy or rent the space listed by that owner.

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    rate = models.FloatField()


class Gallery(models.Model):
    rent = models.ForeignKey(Rental, related_name="galleries")
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TAGS, null=True, blank=True)


BUYER_CHOICES = (
  ('B', 'Buy'),
  ('R', 'Rent'),
)

class Contact(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rental = models.ForeignKey(Rental, related_name="rent")
    email_id = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    buyer_choice = models.CharField(choices=BUYER_CHOICES, max_length=1, null=False, blank=False)


class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ('image', 'tag',)

class RentalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    galleries = GallerySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        fields = ('__all__')
```

UPDATED RentAPIView CODE AS PER @Remi

```
class RentAPIView(APIView):
  serializer_class = RentalSerializer
  parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)
  def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
    """
     Returns a list of rents (or just rent if token is given)
    """
    reply = {}
    try:
        rents = Rental.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        # code is updated here 
        buyer_id = self.request.query_params.get('buyer_id', None)
        if buyer_id:
            rents = rents.filter(user__contact_set__buyer_id=buyer_id)
        if token:
            rent = rents.get(id=token)
            reply['data'] = RentalSerializer(rent).data
        else:
            reply['data'] = RentalSerializer(rents, many=True).data
    except Rental.DoesNotExist:
        return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
    except:
        return error.UnknownError().as_response()
    else:
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Sorry for posting long code. I just wanted to show i tried my best to design effective rest api but could not solve the last 2 problem.

Can anyone kindly help me to understand on how to handle the following criteria?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using the viewsets. In your case, the ModelViewSet would do, if you override your `get_queryset` function in order to prefilter your queryset by anything you want. For Example:

```
class RentAPIViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RentalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # if requesting something like /api/rent?buyer_id=1
        buyer_id = self.request.query_params.get('buyer_id', None)
        if buyer_id:
            return Rental.objects.filter(rent__buyer__id=buyer_id)
        return Rental.objects.all()
```

This would be much cleaner uses the core-functionality of DRF. That being said, back to your question, you could use some of the logic above to extend your api view:

**with query params (you could also go with the kwargs approach like you did with the token):**

```
class RentAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = RentalSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)
    def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        """
         Returns a list of rents (or just rent if token is given)
        """
        reply = {}
        try:
            # first of your two remaining problems
            # if requesting something like /api/rent?buyer_id=1
            buyer_id = self.request.query_params.get('buyer_id', None)

            rents = Rental.objects.filter(user=request.user)

            if buyer_id:
                rents = rents.filter(rent__buyer__id=buyer_id)

            if token:
                rent = rents.get(id=token)
                reply['data'] = RentalSerializer(rent).data
            else:
                reply['data'] = RentalSerializer(rents, many=True).data
        except Rental.DoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
        except:
            return error.UnknownError().as_response()
        else:
            return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The last of your problems doesn't return Rent-Objects, but rather User objects, so this should be done in a differen API view.

Comment: I get "msg": "Unknown Error",  "code": 500 when i do /api/v1/rent?buyer_id=1

Comment: sorry, didn't see your "related" name there. Updated the query

Comment: i get empty list when using rent__buyer__id=buyer_id

Comment: Are you sure, that the user from which the request is coming actually has rentals for the buyer (User) with id 1? ;)

Comment: Yes it worked and sorry i checked the wrong data. Can you explain me how should i handle the last part(User objects) in theory?

Comment: With your approach, you would create a new `UserAPIView` and filter the `User` objects with something like `filter(contact_set__rental__id=rental_id)`.